# How to restore SQL SERVER 2008 database in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have created a database in SQL Server 2008, My database have more then 100 tables, but when i am trying to restore the database in SQL Server 2005, then its not allowing me to restore.

Does any one have idea how to do that, I tried the same using generate script but it doesnot work for me.

Thanks in advance.

Kamal Kant Pansari

Comment: If you're using backup/restore, you can't do it backwards. The work around is scripting. If you're trying scripting and getting errors please let us know what specific problems you're getting.

Answer (score 3):

- Use the scripting wizard in SQL Server 2008 to script data as well as schemas into SQL Server 2005 compatibility mode.
- Run "Generate SQL Server Scripts" wizard in SQL Server Management Studio (once Object Explorer is connected to the appropriate instance) by right clicking on database and selecting "Tasks –> Generate Scripts."
- Click "Script all objects in selected database" & then click "Next."
- Change script options: Specifically, set "Script for Server Version" to "SQL Server 2005" and set "Script Data" to "True". (SQL Server 2000 is also supported.) If you are putting the database on a new instance for the first time, make sure the "Script Database Create" option is set to "True." Click "Next" when you are happy with options.
- Finish the wizard.

Answer (score -1):

The conversation in this thread may be of interest: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic584539-357-1.aspx